# Multiple page breaks in ms macros

Tags: groff

In groff using ms macros, how can I insert multiple page breaks one after another?

This only produces one new page before the next paragraph (as expected):

```
.bp
.bp
```

However this also only produces one new page before the next paragraph:

```
.bp +2
```

I can't find anything relating to page breaks in `man 7 groff_ms`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the start of a page, the ms macros put troff into no-space mode to avoid unwanted gaps. It can be turned off with the command `.rs`. Eg

```
.bp
.rs
.bp
.rs
.bp
```